# Assertion failed: (use_empty() && "Uses remain when a value is destroyed!")

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

```
for (Module::global_iterator I = M.global_begin(), E = M.global_end(); I != E; ++I) {
    GlobalVariable* GV = I;
    if(!GV->hasInitializer())  
        continue;

    ConstantArray* array = dyn_cast<ConstantArray>(GV->getInitializer());      
    if(array){
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < array->getNumOperands(); i++){
            ConstantExpr* ce = dyn_cast<ConstantExpr>(array->getOperand(i));
            if(ce == 0)
                continue;

            ce->getAsInstruction();  //if add, get error!!!

        }
        continue;
    }
}
```

why ce->getAsInstruction() will cause Uses remain when a value is destroyed!

Answer (score 1):

`getAsInstruction` creates a new `Instruction`, but doesn't *insert* it anywhere. If you dump the `Module`, you'll find that you don't see the `Instruction` it created, again because it hasn't been added to a `BasicBlock`. You need to choose where that instruction will go, using something like

> Instruction* I = ce->getAsInstruction();
>   I->insertBefore(OtherInstruction);

Since you didn't do that, when the `Constant` is destroyed these `Instruction`s will still be in memory, and they use (contain pointers to) the `Constants` that were operands of your `ce`. Thus "Uses remain when a value [in this case, the original Constant's operands] is destroyed".

Comment: If I use opt to load this pass,It's will cause Uses remain when a value is destroyed. but use clang -mllvm -xxx to use pass It's run well.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use opt to load this pass,It's will cause Uses remain when a value is destroyed. but use clang -mllvm -xxx to use pass It's run well.

That's because clang cheats; for performance it skips all of the llvm memory cleanup phase and just exits to the operating system. The check for unparented Instructions never runs.

If you're interested, you can actually stop clang from skipping that phase. Clang runs itself with a different command line (clang -cc1 [other flags]), and you need to modify that second command. To get the -cc1 line, place the flag "-###" right after clang. It must be the first argument to clang, -### is position sensitive. That will make clean print out its -cc1 command to the terminal instead of running it. Edit that line to remove "-disable-free" then run it yourself and clang should give the same error as opt.